# Modify multiple fields of an object in an Enumerable at the same time in C#

Tags: c#

If I have an Enumerable of objects and want to modify multiple fields of a single one that I already know the index, I currently do:

```
var myObject = myEnumerable[index];
myObject.one = 1;
myObject.two = 2;
```

Is there a way to compact that? To make it simpler?

As an example, in VB you can do:

```
With myEnumerable[index]
    .one = 1
    .two = 2
End With
```

PS: `using` doesn't work here as the object would need to implement `IDisposable`, we don't' always control the object. I'm looking for a generic way to do this.

Comment: This has been proposed: [#1534](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1534), [#2580](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2580), and others. Use a temporary variable -- you'll notice that it's 1 line shorter then the VB version anyway, so the VB version isn't really more compact. If you really want to shorten things, define methods which let you do `myEnumerable[index].WithOne(1).WithTwo(2)`

Comment: Very much an opinion of course, but I'd just accept the C# syntax as it is. It is as simple as it gets. If you have to update a ton of properties, you're probably performing some logical operation for which you can write a method in the target class with a decent name (which of course wouldn't fly if you don't own the object).

Answer (score 0):

Handmade way of obtaining what you wanted. You can use it on every object.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var item = new Item
        {
            One = 0,
            Two = 0
        };

        item.SetProperties(new string[] { "One", "Two" }, new object[] { 1, 2 });
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public int One { get; set; }
    public int Two { get; set; }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static void SetProperties<T>(this T obj, IEnumerable<string> propertiesNames, IEnumerable<object> propertiesValues)
    {
        if (propertiesNames.Count() != propertiesValues.Count())
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();

        for (int i = 0; i < propertiesNames.Count(); i++)
        {
            var property = properties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == propertiesNames.ElementAt(i));

            if (property is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException();
            }

            property.SetValue(obj, propertiesValues.ElementAt(i));
        }
    }

    public static void SetFields<T>(this T obj, IEnumerable<string> fieldsNames, IEnumerable<object> fieldsValues)
    {
        if (fieldsNames.Count() != fieldsValues.Count())
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        var fields = obj.GetType().GetFields();

        for (int i = 0; i < fieldsNames.Count(); i++)
        {
            var field = fields.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == fieldsNames.ElementAt(i));

            if (field is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException();
            }

            field.SetValue(obj, fieldsValues.ElementAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```